# Web CMS supporting Asp.Net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, content-management-system

I have created an Asp.Net MVC 2 application. Now i want to integrate it with content management system. Is there any free or opensource CMS which supports MVC2. I tried KOOBOO CMS but i couldn't get how do I integrate my application into it and create a CMS site.

Answer (score 0):

Orchard is Microsoft's open source CMS using MVC 3: http://orchard.codeplex.com/